# What does console command voice_enable 0 do?

Tags: dota-2

I noticed that voice chat makes my games laggy and unplayable. 
I'm trying to disable it completely so it won't hog my network resource anymore. 
While searching for a solution I found this console command to disable it, but I haven't tested it thoroughly.

```
voice_enable 0
```

By inputting this command into console window, I didn't get any message nor error returned. Is there anyone able to clarify this?

Comment: Well...um...it does exactly what it says on the tin. It disables voice. You can just try to join a game and see if there's voice chat going on to try out if it worked? (Even though voice_enable strikes me as a Source game kind of thing and obviously I didn't do research.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when `voice_enable` is set a zero (`0`), you **won't receive any voice communication** signal (you could say the voice chat is muted) AND **your microphone won't send any data** to your teammates either.

It mutes the voice over ip system (VoIP) for yourself.

Answer (score 1):

According to [the wiki](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/List_of_Console_Commands) :

```
voice_enable 0/1 Toggle voice transmit and receive.
```

The default value is `1` so by default voice transmit and recieve is enabled.